# Xgboost TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Tags: python, xgboost

I am trying to run sample code using Xgboost package with xgbfir package. The code I am trying to execute is as follows:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris, load_boston
import xgboost as xgb
import xgbfir

# loading database
boston = load_boston()

# doing all the XGBoost magic

xgb_rmodel = xgb.XGBRegressor().fit(boston['data'], boston['target'])

# saving to file with proper feature names
xgbfir.saveXgbFI(xgb_rmodel, feature_names=boston.feature_names, OutputXlsxFile = 'bostonFI.xlsx')

# loading database
iris = load_iris()

# doing all the XGBoost magic
xgb_cmodel = xgb.XGBClassifier().fit(iris['data'], iris['target'])

# saving to file with proper feature names
xgbfir.saveXgbFI(xgb_cmodel, feature_names=iris.feature_names, OutputXlsxFile = 'irisFI.xlsx')
```

I am getting the following error and can't understand why this is happening. It seems that booster() is not being able to be called within Xgboost, but I have no clue how to fix this or where to start.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-152-af422c4cc325> in <module>()
     10 
     11 # saving to file with proper feature names
---> 12 xgbfir.saveXgbFI(xgb_rmodel, feature_names=boston.feature_names, OutputXlsxFile = 'bostonFI.xlsx')
     13 
     14 

/Users/xxxxxxx/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xgbfir/main.pyc in saveXgbFI(booster, feature_names, OutputXlsxFile, MaxTrees, MaxInteractionDepth, MaxDeepening, TopK, MaxHistograms, SortBy)
    589     if not 'get_dump' in dir(booster):
    590         if 'booster' in dir(booster):
--> 591             booster = booster.booster()
    592         else:
    593             return -20

T

ypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Could this be due to versioning of Xgboost? I would greatly appreciate any help with helping resolve this.

Comment: I am not getting any error with version `xgboost==0.6a2` and `xgbfir==0.2` on Ubuntu.

Comment: This issue might be related to a bad installation of the packages (even though xgboost is running just fine except the booster function). I am running this on a mac and versions are xgboost==0.6 and xgbfir==0.2. Do you know an easy way to upgrade xgboost==to 0.6a2?

Comment: Well I reinstalled the xgboost package and it still does not work, I have no clue how to fix this or where to go.

Answer (score 0):

xgbfir.saveXgbFI(xgb_rmodel.get_booster(), feature_names=boston.feature_names, OutputXlsxFile = 'bostonFI.xlsx')

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow!! Try to avoid comment in answer unless you have specific answer. Please use comment box below and Once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post. :)